# Onepage-scroll not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

i don't understand what's happening to my project. I can run it easily on Chrome, Firefox, IE & Opera but it's not running on Safari.
It’s only working on first load on a new tab. And will not work when you reload.

Controller.js

```
controller: function($scope, $state, $auth, Info){
      $(".main").onepage_scroll({
        sectionContainer: "section",
        easing: "ease",
        animationTime: 700,
        pagination: true,
        updateURL: false,
        beforeMove: function(index) {},
        afterMove: function(index) {},
        loop: false,
        keyboard: true,
        responsiveFallback: false,
        direction: "vertical",
        navigation: true,
        navigationPosition: 'right'
      });
      $scope.down = function () {
        $(".main").moveDown();
      }
      $scope.up = function () {
        $(".main").moveUp();
      }
      $scope.getNews = function () {
        $scope.infos = Info.$search();
      }
      $state.go($auth.isAuthenticated() ? 'root.dashboard' : 'root.landing.home');
    },
    resolve: {
      lang: ['$translatePartialLoader', function($translatePartialLoader){
        $translatePartialLoader.addPart('root/landing');
      }],
    }
```

thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/) instead?

Comment: @Alvaro I've tried to fullpage.js but that causes problems with angularjs.

Comment: Which problem does it causes that one page scroll doesn't? Have you review [these topics](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=angular) You might have to use `destroy` and initialize the plugin again.

Comment: @Alvaro i'll try use fullPage.js again, thanks.